# C# - Display instantly a string in textbox coming from a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm in the 1st form,
so I want to pass the ID to the 2nd Form and display it there in a textbox.
So I did this.

In form 1:Assume inside using{}

```
public partial class First_Form: Form
{
   public void test(){
        Main_Menu_Form f2 = new Main_Menu_Form();
       f2.selectedid = id;
        f2.Show();
   }
}
```

In form 2: Assume inside using{}

```
public partial class Main_Menu_Form: Form
{
    public int selectedid;
    public Main_Menu_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textbox1.Text = selectedid;
    }
  }
```

What I want is when I opened the new Form (Form2)
I want to display the selected id immediately in the form2 textbox as the Form2 loads.
I don't know whats wrong with this, this should display because when I tried to place textbox1.Text = selectedid; , it will work. But on form initialization or load, It won't.

Form 2: I tried also this but won't work

```
    private void Main_Menu_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textbox1.Text = selectedid;
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to do that.  Just set it right after you create the form instance.

Comment: in the first code you're setting some property called `selected_id` and in the second code you're referencing a different property called `selectedid`. And the public field you show is named `id`. Could that be it? You should show your definition of the property you're trying to set. Also, are you creating an instance of `NewForm` or `Main_Menu_Form`? The code you've shown is not consistent and give us nothing to reproduce the problem.

Comment: i edited it already, id->selectedid instead in the 2nd form, my bad. But this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You are modifying your code sample with code that doesn't compile. You should copy and paste the **exact** code that you're running, otherwise there may be problems that are getting lost in translation. For example `f2.show();` would give a compile error because `Show()` has a capital `S`, and you would have to call `.ToString()` on `selectedid` when trying to set the `Text` property of the textbox. Don't show fake code in your sample, show actual code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a public property in `Form2` for the selected id, and in the `Form_Load` event, set the `Text` property of the textbox to that value:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int SelectedId { get; set; }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = SelectedId.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in `Form1`, you set the value of that property and show the form (I'm using a button `Click` event):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.SelectedId = 100;
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked!  public int SelectedId { get; set; } is lacking in my code. I wonder why

Comment: You can replace that with `public int selectedid;` (like you show in your sample) and it should still work (after you update the other references to `selectedid` instead of `SelectedId`). But public fields are usually not a good idea, so I used a property.

Comment: Why not just update textbox on `SelectedId`'s setter?

Comment: @Rotem That's another way to do it. I'm assuming that since it's in a textbox, the user can change it, at which point the property may also be changed so the first form can consume it.

Comment: I think that it is better to override OnLoad of Form2 instead of subscribe to its own event. Also can set id on ctor.